# Finding the first ocurrence of a string below a given cell?

Tags: excel

I've been trying to figure this out but I don't seem to get it right.

I have a spreadsheet with reports for different categories detailed by day (e.g. Toys, Drinks, General Store, Meat Store, Veggies, etc)

So, my spreadsheet looks something like this:

```
Toys

Day        Me    Wife   Kid1  Kid2
9/28/13    0     0      0     0
10/1/13    29    3      0     0
10/2/13    0     7      34    25
10/4/13    0     0      0     0
AVERAGE    29    5      34    25
.

Drinks

Day        Me    Wife   Kid1  Kid2
9/30/13    102   15     0     0
10/1/13    0     0      25    0
AVERAGE    102   20     0     0
```

etc etc

So the idea would be that I need to be able to find the Average row number for each different category, but I can't just look for it easily because in one category there might be expenses on more months (hence, more rows between the category's title and the average row). Any clues?

Comment: What do u mean by `Average row number`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
=ROW()+MATCH("AVERAGE",$A2:$A$1001,0)-1
```

[image]

The row reference to A2 is variable and you can paste it next to the category of interest. The row reference to A1001 is just far enough down in your spreadsheet to include all the data, and is fixed (but doesn't have to be).

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this perhaps:

```
=MATCH("AVERAGE",INDIRECT("A"&MATCH("Drinks",A:A,0)&":A1000"),0)+MATCH("Drinks",A:A,0)-1
```

`MATCH("Drinks",A:A,0)` returns the row number of `Drinks`

Which is used by `INDIRECT` and to convert into a range, from which `MATCH` then returns the number of rows after that header. Add to the number of rows before `Drinks` and remove 1 to get the actual row number.

Change the range of `A1000` accordingly. I assumed a maximum of 1000 rows here.

Edit, if you have cross-sheet referencing, you need to change the formula to:

```
=MATCH("AVERAGE",INDIRECT("'Sheetname'!A"&MATCH("Drinks",'Sheetname'!A:A,0)&":A1000"),0)+MATCH("Drinks",'Sheetname'!A:A,0)-1
```

Assuming `Sheetname` is the name of that sheet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this works like a charm, unluckily I need to reference to this table from another sheet and that's causing errors again.. still, thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @IñakiGuastalli Oh, you could have specified it, that's easy to fix :) What's the sheet name?